# Grep logs for productIds and group results by productId?

Tags: bash, command-line, grep

I'm not too familiar with some of the fancier aspects of grep or similar commands, but this is what I'm trying to do.

I have an application log that I have grepped and wrote the results into a file. (grepped for a specific error).

Now I want to grep that new file by productId (there's a productId per error message, but the other contents of the error message vary), and group the productIds together with a # indicating how many times the product id showed up in the log.

Example 
Log:

```
[ERROR] Some class, error info..., for request 13143, with productId=1AHREA4315, location=4314131, timestamp=1431314143141
[ERROR] other class, other error..., for request 13145, with productId=ATAC15414319, location=431531, timestamp=14314314151
... (thousands of errors, many for the same productId)
```

Example desired output:(productId, count)

```
1AHREA4315 134 
ATAC15414319 2341
431AREAB341 3
```

etc.

Doesn't have to be pretty, I'm just trying to get data about what productId caused issues and which ones came in more than others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that product IDs do not have a blank space on them, the following would work for many Bash versions:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Assuming that Product IDs do not have a blank space
grep -o -P 'productId=.*? ' /folder/file > /tmp/pid-holder

#cleaning up everything but the product id value
sed 's/^..........//' /tmp/pid-holder > /tmp/pid-holder2 && sed 's/..$//' /tmp/pid-holder2 > /tmp/pid-holder3

#counting and storing result on a file
sort /tmp/pid-holder3 | uniq -c > /tmp/result

exit 0
```

The result will be stored on the file /tmp/result